# Is it obstruction of justice to advise someone not to answer questions from the police?

Tags: obstruction

If two people X and Y are together and the police come and start interrogating X and Y says, "Don't answer any of their questions."., can the police then arrest Y for obstruction of justice?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-7o9xYp7eE

Answer (score 1):

### No

Advising someone to do something that the police will shortly be telling them they have the right to do can hardly be obstruction.